# Return result via column view instead row view in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to know if there is a way to return my result via column. Simple Select statement will return like

```
 _________________
| id  |  name    | 
|  1  | abc      | 
|  2  | abc1     | 
|  3  | abc2     |
```

is there a way to retrieve my result like this

```
| 1 |  abc  | 2 | abc1| 3 | abc2|
```

or like

```
|1   | 2  | 3  |
|abc |abc1|abc2|
```

i am only returning 4 columns, and i am using the data as header of other queries. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `PIVOT`. You need to use `MAX` and `GROUP BY` to simulate `PIVOT`.

```
SELECT  Id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN name END) col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 2 THEN name END) col2
FROM    Table1
GROUP   BY Id
```

You need to decide based on which criteria you need to group the data. Try this example.

Comment: my result is 
..........................................................................................................................................................


1 abc.....................................................................................................................................................................
2 ___abc1.............................................................................................................................................................
3________abc2

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
select group_concat(id,"|",name SEPARATOR '|') from T;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

### Query

```
SELECT 
MAX
(
    CASE id WHEN 1 
    THEN name 
    ELSE NULL END
) AS `1`,
MAX
(
    CASE id WHEN 2 
    THEN name 
    ELSE NULL END
) AS `2`,
MAX
(
    CASE id WHEN 3 
    THEN name 
    ELSE NULL END
) AS `3` 
FROM tbl;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c37a0/5)

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem because they give me clue, now this is my code, I want to share it

```
SELECT
  MIN( CONCAT(title,"\n", DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%h:%i %p')) ) col1,
  MAX( CONCAT(title,"\n", DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%h:%i %p')) ) col2
 from table
```

thanks everyone